# Bad programming practice to have a method dependent on another method?

Tags: java, methods

So I have a method which instantiates a instance field `String[][] myArray` with values.

```
String[][] myArray;

public String[][] getArray() {
    // CREATES, RETURNS & INSTANTIATES myArray WITH ARRAY
}
```

However, then I have a method called getAvg() which gets the average of a column in the array. This uses the instance field which is now instantiated with data. Trouble is, this will obviously not run if the array has not been created first. Within my program, I create the array before calling for the average and it works. But I'm wondering if this is the most elegant of methods and if this could even be bad practice.

```
public double getAvg() {
    // CALCULATES AND RETURNS AVERAGE
}
```

I previously recreated the array within the getAvg() method. However, this lead me to me thinking that this would be redundant and inefficient.

So, what do you think?

Comment: Don't worry about "efficiency", worry about *clarity*. Often times in programming there is too much focus put on side-effects (methods that depend on shared *mutable* state). However in cases like this, it is much cleaner to "pass a value in" and "get a value out", as you have noted :) This reduces coupling, increases thread-safety, and allows re-entrance.

Comment: Where is the data for your array coming from? an inputStream? I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking. You have a String array and you are computing avg. You should post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is bad practice.  In general (there are exceptions, but not many), all the data a class needs should be ready by the time the constructor returns.  What about renaming `getArray` to `initializeMyArray`, making it private, and placing a call to `initializeMyArray` in the constructor?  Then, whenever some outside code calls `getAvg()`, `myArray` will have been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to pass the data structure into `getAve()`:

```
public static double getAve(String [][] values) {
    double ave = 0.0;
    // What are you averaging?  That's a matrix of Strings you're passing....
    return ave;
}
```

That eliminates the dependency.  It'll be useful even for clients besides your class.

Why are you using that data structure?  Where do the doubles to average come from?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely better to not have your getAvg() function call getArray() if it can be avoided, otherwise you will be creating a new String[][] every time you call getAvg().  A good rule of thumb to follow when calling methods within other methods is, do it if it makes the code easier to understand and doesn't make the program slower.

Question though... is there any reason why you can't use a double[][] instead?  Parsing strings into doubles is very slow, and I'm assuming that's what you're doing every time your getAvg() function looks to the String[][] for column data.  Using double[][] would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the constructor of your class to force the array creation at instantiation time:

```
public class MyClass {
    String[][] myArray;

    public MyClass() {
        getArray();
    }

    public String[][] getArray() {
        // CREATES, RETURNS & INSTANTIATES myArray WITH ARRAY
    }
    public double getAvg() {
        // CALCULATES AND RETURNS AVERAGE
    }
}
```

And you use it like so:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); // class is instantiated and getArray() is run automatically
myClass->getAvg(); // your code is now safe to run on that array
```